# Javascript function TypeError but only on substring() strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, forgive me for the lengthy title. My code snipits will be at the bottom of the page.

I've created a javascript program that changes the rows and columns of a pivot table to a predefined value. Initially I did this by using `$(".Dropdown").val(value).trigger("change");` which worked well as long as I didn't use my javascript to insert the values.

IE `<onclick="presetFunction('count', 'Heatmap', ['ClassNum'], ['Grade'])">` typed onto the page works fine. However, using a javascript to place the above line onto the page will not.

When I looked at the console I get this error: "TypeError: opts.aggregators[aggregator.val(...)] is not a function", I checked my types (in case my string dissection changed the type), that wasn't the issue. I've checked values and that is also not the issue.

Here is the code snippits I'm using:

Element I'm attaching the onclick to:

```
<li id="one" class="Barchart">
    <a href="#one">Barchart<span>5</span></a>
    <ul id="bchart" class="sub-menu">
    </ul>
</li>
```

Javascript that moves things around:

```
function presetFunction(Agg, Rend, Col, Row) {
    $(".pvtRenderer").val(Rend).trigger("change");
    $(".pvtAggregator").val(Agg).trigger("change");
    $(".label.label-info").each(function (index, element) {
        test = $(element).html();
        test = test.substring(6, test.length - 42);
        if ((Col.indexOf(test)) != -1)
            $(".pvtAxisContainer.pvtRows.ui-sortable").append(element);
        else if (Row.indexOf(test) != -1)
            $(".pvtAxisContainer.pvtHorizList.pvtCols.ui-sortable").append(element);
        else
            $(".pvtAxisContainer.pvtUnused.pvtHorizList.ui-sortable").append(element);
        $(element).triggerHandler("");
    });
}
```

Giving a string to test here:

```
function loadPresets() {
    var presets = "\'count\', \'Bar Chart\', [\'ProfLastName\'], [\'Grade\']";
    var sep = presets.indexOf(",");
    var style = presets.substr(0, sep).trim();

    presets = presets.substr(sep + 1, presets.length).trim();
    sep = presets.indexOf(",");

    var type = presets.substr(0, sep).trim();
    presets = presets.substr(sep + 1, presets.length).trim();
    sep = presets.indexOf("]");

    var row = presets.substr(0, sep + 1);
    presets = presets.substr(sep + 2, presets.length);

    var col = presets.trim();
    var link = '<li><a href=\"#\" id=\"b01\"><em>01</em>Teacher vs. Grade</a></li>';

    $("#bchart").append(link);
    $("#b01").click(function () {
        presetFunction(style, type, row, col);
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
CF

Comment: Assigning a value to *presets* then splitting it up to assign to other variables seems like an overly complex way to do that.

Comment: I was doing that just to test the function. I'm actually using php to pull strings in that format. I figured I should show what the string looked like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the fact you have the single quotes inside of the variables. Get rid of them.

Your onclick looks something like this

```
presetFunction( "'style'", "'type'", "'row'", "'col'");
```